# Weird behaviour with javascript Arrays and promises

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous

I've been experiencing some behaviour that I don't understand to do with JavaScript arrays. As viewed from the firefox console savedMessages[channelId] displayed differently at different points.
[Both of these should be the same but they are displayed and act differently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgzJX.png)

They look the similar when they are expanded

["Array[]"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7XJz.png)

["Array() [ Li, Li, ...]"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlysy.png)

The first instance skips foreach functions as if the elements inside do not exist and I see it when I run this.

```
getMessagesFromDB(channelId, 1, 60).then((messages) => {
    savedMessages[channelId] = messages;
    console.log(savedMessages);               //This is what produces the Array[] result
    
    console.log(savedMessages[channelId]);
    savedMessages[channelId].forEach((message)=>{       //This is completely skipped    
            messageContainer.append(message);
    });
    resolve();
})
```

This started appearing when I switched a section of the code producing the elements in getMessagesFromDM to include a promise as another function has to gather extra information from the database.
Please could anybody explain what this might be and how it could be fixed.

Also appologies if I haven't explained my issue very well. I'm pretty new to JS.

Code that fills the messages array as requested

```
function formatMessage(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        newMessageLi = document.getElementById("chatTemplate").cloneNode(true);             //clone template
        newMessageLi.style.display = "";                                                    //set attributes
        newMessageLi.id = "";
        newMessageLi.setAttribute("data-senderId", data["senderId"]);
        newMessageLi.setAttribute("data-dateTime", data["dateTimeSent"]);
        
        let displayUsername = newMessageLi.querySelector("[data-display='username']");      //get data locations
        let displayDateTime = newMessageLi.querySelector("[data-display='dateTime']");
        let displayText = newMessageLi.querySelector("[data-display='text']");

        let dateTime = new Date(data["dateTimeSent"]);                                      //turn datetime into date object

        getUsernameFromDatabase(data["senderId"]).then((username) => {
            displayUsername.innerHTML = "<b>" + username + "</b>";                      //insert data
            displayDateTime.innerHTML = dateTime.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0") + "/" + (dateTime.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0") + "/" + dateTime.getFullYear().toString() + " " + dateTime.getHours().toString().padStart(2, "0") + ":" + dateTime.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0");
            displayText.innerHTML = data["textContent"];
            
            resolve(newMessageLi);
        })

    });

function getMessagesFromDB(channelId, startIndex, endIndex) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let messages = {};
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onload = function() {
            let messages = [];
            console.log("Recieved Data:");
            let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(data);
            Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {            
                let value = data[key];
                value["dateTimeSent"] = parseInt(value["dateTimeSent"]);
                formatMessage(value).then((newMessage) => {
                    messages.push(newMessage);
                })  
            }); 
            console.log("Data");
            console.log(messages);
                    
            resolve(messages);
        }
        xhttp.open("GET", "fetchMessages.php?channelId=" + encodeURIComponent(channelId) + "&startIndex=" +  encodeURIComponent(startIndex) + "&endIndex=" +  encodeURIComponent(endIndex));       
        xhttp.send();  
    })
}
```

Comment: There must be a problem with the `getMessagesFromDB` code (or anything else with access to the object), as it is modified after you have logged it. You probably expected the promise returned by `getMessagesFromDB()` not to be fulfilled earlier than this. Please [edit] your question to include the code that creates/fills the `messages`, then we might be able to provide a concrete solution.

Comment: Btw, your call `resolve()` suggests that you use the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it), but you'll need to show more code to verify

Comment: @Bergi - It's inside another promise which is what that is resolving

Comment: "*It's inside another promise*" - yes, that is exactly the problem. You shouldn't wrap it, but rather just chain `.then()` calls

Comment: The problem with `getMessagesFromDB` is that it calls `formatMessage(value).then((newMessage) => { messages.push(newMessage); })`, but immediately does `resolve(messages)` without waiting for the `formatMessage` calls to push the messages. You should remove the formatting from the `fetchMessages(` function and only fulfill the promise with `data`. The use `fetchMessages(…).then(data => Promise.all(Object.values(data).map(formatMessage)))` which allows waiting for each formatting request

Comment: …although really you should change your *fetchMessages.php* backend to already include the sender username in each message, so that you don't have to make N+1 http requests